# Global back button in Sencha Touch2

Tags: navigation, sencha-touch-2

I implemented a sencha touch 2 app which contains a navigation list within another navigation list.

In order to make the app more clean, I removed the headers of the navigation views as there were two headers beneath each other whenever the inner navigation list was being displayed.

Instead, I created a global back button in the footer of the application. My question is, how can you go back one page wherever you are in the application.

When using the .pop method, you need to specify which navigation list would you like to pop a view from which won't work in my case.

Basically, since when you click on a button, another view is loaded, I think there is some way how this can be revered, i.e. having like a history.go(-1) but instead of a redirect, it would go back to the view which redirected you here.

Can this be achieved?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

...I would recommend not having a NavigationView inside a NavigationView. What is the reason for needing both?

Otherwise you might be able to keep track of the last view accessed and pop to that on back. [NavigationView.pop(ViewObject)](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.navigation.View-method-pop) - specifically this option: 'If an Object, the pops to a matching view instance.'